# Verilog HDL ? operator

Tags: verilog

What does the **?** do in Verilog?

For ex: what does that mean of the following command?

```
input first_din;
input  [7:0]   din;
output [127:0] parity;
reg    [127:0] parity;
wire   [7:0]   feedback;

assign feedback = din ^ (first_din ? 8'b0 : parity[127:120]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, `?` is part of the "Conditional operator" (`?:`).  Refer to the free IEEE Std 1800-2012, *Table 11-1—Operators and data types*.  It is used to model a multiplexer.  In your case, `first_din` is the select, and `8'b0` and `parity[127:120]` are the data inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to ? : Operator in C, this operator works as simple if else block.

```
 b  =  exp. a   ?   value_1  :  value_2
```

equals to

```
if ( exp. a )//if true
    b = value_1;
else 
    b = value_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is like a typical multiplexer 2-to-1 .

Inputs :  A , B , SEL 
Outputs : OUT

Function :

```
IF (SEL = 1) THEN OUT = B , ELSE OUT = A

OUT = SEL ? B : A ;
```

Warning : if SEL = Z ( High impedance OR floating ) THEN OUT = A 
This is the main difference with the typical multiplexer 2-to-1

The function of the Typical multiplexer 2-to-1 is:

```
IF (SEL = 1) THEN OUT = B , ELSE IF(SEL = 0) OUT = A ;
```